# Best way to structure MongoDB data for date specific settings

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm modelling information in MongoDB for a booking system I've been working on.

Every date that can be booked has a series of default 'settings' e.g. it's not blocked, and the opening hours are '12:00'-'15:00' and '16:00-18:00' for example.

However, I need to store information about dates that deviate from these default 'settings'. This is how I currently structure these documents.

```
new mongoose.Schema({  
  blocked: Boolean,
  date: { type: Date, required: true },
  openingHours: {
    Monday: [String],
    Tuesday: [String],
    Wednesday: [String],
    Thursday: [String],
    Friday: [String],
    Saturday: [String],
    Sunday: [String]
 },
 messages: [String]
});
```

So for each date that has settings different from the default, it will have a document containing its unique settings.

1. I'm sure there is a much better and efficient way to structure this, but am not too sure what that looks like.
2. I'm also interested to know how is the best way to remove these documents when they no longer contain relevant settings. For example, if a document is created but then updated so that it now resembles the same settings that are the default, I would ideally want to remove the document entirely as it's no longer relevant. Would it be best to do this before updating the document - check if the document would equal the default settings if the updates were applied and if so delete the doc, otherwise update it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you should consider an array structure instead with a `day` field? This way you can perform an array query if needed, rather than having to perform a large `$or` query for each day of the week, e.g. `openingHours: [ {day: 'Monday', hours: [String]} ]`. You have the additional benefit of only needing to account for the specific days you want to override as well, rather than requiring a field for each day regardless of whether or not there is an overriding setting.

Comment: @B.Fleming good suggestion, that improves this. I was half expecting a more critical view on the way I was planning to structure this data though, perhaps it's not so bad after all.